# Bad reception of RS485 on Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino

I'm using a sensor that sends ASCII data frames over RS485 every second. I use an RS485 to TTL converter to read them in series on an Arduino Uno.

The problem is that I'm not getting the right values. By looking for similarities in the typical frame I'm supposed to be receiving and the ones I'm actually receiving, I've found that I need to perform the following steps to translate them:

- Inversion of bit values (e.g. 1001 becomes 0110)
- Conversion of the inverted binary value to ASCII

**Wiring diagram (sorry for the diagram I don't have access to clean software at the moment) :**
[image]

**Arduino code:**

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(0, 1);

#define EN 7

const unsigned long timeout = 500;
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
byte c;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  mySerial.begin(9600);
  digitalWrite(EN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(EN, LOW);
  delay(2000);
}

void loop() {
  while (mySerial.available()) {
    c = mySerial.read();
    //Serial.print(c, HEX);Serial.print(",");
    Serial.print(c, HEX);
    //Serial.print(",");

    previousMillis = millis();
  }

  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
  if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= timeout) {
    Serial.println();
    previousMillis = currentMillis;
  }
}
```

Comment: So what's the question? And what is the sensor, any link to data sheet what it outputs?

Comment: The question is: Does anyone have any idea why this conversion is necessary? This is not normal operation, it seems to me. The sensor is an anemometer and the datasheet is paid for, and I can't post it or link to it.

Comment: You have been suggested already to check swapping of A and B, that is my firm belief that it's wrong, unless you can provide the sensor type, data sheet and protocol.

Comment: Not sure what A- and B- is. In RS485 the diffential pair is sometimes called A and B. In RS422 we have Tx+ Tx- Rx+ Rx-. This seems to mix the two concepts? Is the sensor transmitting as simplex (most are), semi-duplex or full duplex?

Comment: Why is the waveform so chunky? Hard straight line segments are extremely rare electrical signals in practice. Was the sample rate or scale appropriate for the measurement?

Comment: May I suggest that when you need to invert the bits in an integer you use the bit wise NOT operator in your language of choice. In C and python that would be the tilde (~)

Comment: @Juno Why did you remove important parts of the question? Also can you verify if your hardware works properly when you don't short out your data wires to scope ground, to actually fix what the problem is, not to work around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Conversion of the frame from hexadecimal to binary
>
> Inversion of bit values (e.g. 1001 becomes 0110)
>
> Conversion of the inverted binary value to ASCII

When you create your software serial object in the Arduino code, use a third parameter:

> SoftwareSerial(rxPin, txPin, inverse_logic)

For example,

> SoftwareSerial mySerial (0,1, true);

or

> SoftwareSerial mySerial (0,1, false);

I don't know which you need, but one of them may (should?) work.

Edit: per feedback from the OP, using the "true" parameter made communication work.

Comment: If the polarity of A/B is currently wrong, simply flipping the bits and shifting in software will not work, because start bit is wrong and later data bits can be implemented as start bit.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
Swapping A and B make that I receive nothing.
I don't see how to "invert the sense of received TTL level signal at the micro-controller".

Comment: Add 'true' parameter makes it work perfectly thank you very much for your help

Comment: So basically the A and B are swapped because it should end up having the same inversion, but some other issue prevents it from working.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, you are connecting one scope probe alone to A and B wires. Which is incorrect as it will short one of the differential data wires to ground and prevents correct operation. And that is causing your data to be not received when you swapped the A/B polarity to correct way which does not require UART inversion.

So it just happens to work when scope grounds one of the wires, when you are incorrectly swapping A and B to receive inverted data, which again causes your need to re-invert the received data in the SoftwareSerial module.

So the correct thing is to disconnect the incorrct scope connection and connect the two modules together with their A and B wires so that software inversion is not needed and it will also work with standard harware UART.

Also if you think all manufacturers agree on which wire is A and which wire is B, they don't and there are two different notations. So the point is to connect the wires correctly regardless of notation, and it may require connecting them directly A/B to A/B or swapping them for A/B to B/A.